# Resetting Plan-Based Subscription In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am trying to develop a system where a user can buy a premium subscription for a certain amount of time (maybe a month or a week) however upon expiration of this subscription, I want to reset the user back to basic plan on Laravel.

I have been researching this, and I was able to find a way that has to do with setting up cron jobs based on the plan subscription length.

Is this the best way possible? And if yes, is there a way I can set up crons in Laravel controllers (i.e after the user's payment is confirmed).

Comment: The Cron jobs shouldnt be user specific. Create just one Cron job that Will handle all subscriptions in bulk.

Comment: That way, I have to make a check for maybe every day at a certain time? that way the user gets added hours till the time elapses?

Comment: Well basicaly yes. But if you set up the task to run just after midnight. They wont get more then some minutes at time when theyre probably not using it anyway...

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about this is to have a date the subscription ends for that user within the database. You can then alter your business logic, ui etc so that they get the correct experience depending on whether this date has passed or not yet.

Comment: Thats probably not the best way to go. Starting with having to check the date on many occasions. Ending with inconsistent states, as maybe many other properties should change when subscription expires.

Comment: I thought of this firstly, but it will require so many requests for checking the validity of the subscription.

Comment: I don't think you would have an issue with inconsistent states. I would have a method on the model like `$user->hasValidSubscription()`. But it depends on what you want to do. If you need other values to change then you could do it within Laravel Scheduler. Checking the date isn't really any different to checking a flag in the database to see if the subscription is valid, you're still going to be running a database query at the end of the day, just checking a different value. Using a date allows you to see the date it expires too rather than just "are they subscribed".